# nginx: how to use rewrite

Tags: django, nginx

I need to hide /it Query portion for SEO request in a django-cms setup.

I tryed with::

```
location /it {
  if ($request_method = 'GET') {
    rewrite ^/it(/?.*) https://my.domain.it$1 ;
  }
}
location / {
    uwsgi_pass  preprod;
    include /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
}
```

everything works correctly except authentication (that is a POST to
/it/admin/). My impression is that 'location /it' doesn't handle a POST and it
doesn't fall back to the more general 'location /'. Is it correct?
What it the std way to achieve a redirect just in case of a GET request?

TIA

Comment: From where does `/it/something` urls come from? Why can't you change post url in html to '/admin/`?

Comment: Sorry for being late in the answer. /it comes from the cms. Even if I fill page /admin whe I submit, the POST is addressed to /it/admin/. I'd like to know how I can configure a location just for GET leaving std behaviour for POST.